# Find shortest path between two vertices in undirected graph

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I must find the shortest path. This gives me the list of all paths. How can I pick the smallest out of these?

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y],L) :- edge(X,Y,L).
path(X,Y,[X|W],L) :- edge(X,Z,L1), path(Z,Y,W,L2), L is L1 + L2.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your program, you can solve this problem with this code:

```
path(X,Y,[X,Y],L):- 
    edge(X,Y,L).

path(X,Y,[X|W],L):- 
    edge(X,Z,L1), 
    path(Z,Y,W,L2), 
    L is L1 + L2.

shortestPath(X,X,[X,X],0):- !.
shortestPath(X,Y,MinP,MinD):-
    findall([L,P],path(X,Y,P,L),Set),
    sort(Set,Sorted),
    Sorted = [[MinD,MinP]|_].

?- shortestPath(1,5,Path,Length).
Length = 3.5,
Path = [1, 2, 5]
```

If you don't want to use `sort/2` (note that `sort/2` removes duplicates), you can wite something like this:

```
shortestPath(X,X,[X,X],0):- !.
shortestPath(X,Y,MinP,MinD):-
    findall([L,P],path(X,Y,P,L),Set),
    splitList(Set,LD,LP),
    min_list(LD,MinD),
    nth1(I,LD,MinD),
    nth1(I,LP,MinP).

splitList([],[],[]).
splitList([[L,D]|T],[L|TP],[D|TD]):-
    splitList(T,TP,TD). 

?- shortestPath(1,5,Path,Length).
    Length = 3.5,
    Path = [1, 2, 5]
    false.
```

So basically, you find all the solutions and pick the smallest one...